# How to Send heic format file to OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, heic

From IOS 11 (if Im not wrong) iPhone increased the use of HEIC format but OPENCV is still not supporting this format.

Maybe you can suggest what is the best practice for sending HEIC to OpenCV from cpp code?

What I have tried

[Libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif) - external and a bit heavy convertor

[Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) - It's python and I need CPP

[opencv_videoio_ffmpeg430_64.dll](https://answers.opencv.org/question/228153/source-code-for-opencv_videoio_ffmpeg430_64dll-to-decode-heic-images/) - Some talking about this .dll but I can't find any other info

The main thoughts are can I convert it to some other more generic format rather to JPEG and etc., is there another way to send HEIC to opencv and maybe some internal info about OpenCV future plans to support heic natively?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Does OpenCV support .HEIC image format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951161/does-opencv-support-heic-image-format). TLDR: there is an open [feature request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14534) to add support for HEIC.

Comment: @PascalGetreuer thanks, I'm not sure it's duplicate, the feature request indeed exist but I need to work it out now, and the question is not asking for other solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question as "how do I get OpenCV's IO library to read HEIC". It sounds like your actual question is "how do I read HEIC in C++". In your question you mention [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif), which looks like a great solution. Certainly more straightforward than invoking Pillow from C++ or the elusive opencv_videoio_ffmpeg430_64.dll (I could not find it either). Are you looking to discuss something more with this post? Or perhaps this is already answered? =)